# angular factory module get promise data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

i have a module factoty that do $http call name: 'containeData'
than i send the data to other factory modul by promise
 name:'divLogicFactory'. i want to send the the object array "arraysOfDives"
to the controller. but the arraysOfDives is alwyas empty.
because the method that fill the array is a call back.
but i dont know how return the object to the controller when the call back is finish. pls help me.

```
var  jsonFactory = angular.module('jsonFactory',[]);

jsonFactory.factory('containerData',function($http,$q){
    var
        defer = $q.defer(),
        data = {};

    data.getDivData = function(){

        return $http({

            method:"get",
            url:"App/metaData/divData.json"
        }).
            then(function(response){

            defer.resolve(response.data);

           // return response.data;//defer.promise;
            return defer.promise;

        },function(error){

            defer.reject(error);
            return defer.promise;

        })
    }

var divLogic = angular.module('divLogic', ['jsonFactory']);

divLogic.factory('divLogicFactory', function (containerData, $q) {



    var divLogicFactory = {};

    divLogicFactory.arraysOfDives = [];




    divLogicFactory.setDivsData = function () {

        **this is the call back method**
        containerData.getDivData().then(function (data) {

            //extract divData from call back
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var
                    height = data[i].height,
                    width = data[i].width,
                    border = data[i].border,
                    positionY = data[i].positionTopY,
                    positionX = data[i].positionLeftX,
                    templateID = data[i].templateID;


                init(height, width, border, positionY, positionX, templateID);

            }




        })
    }

    function init(height, width, border, positionY, positionX, templateID) {


        var $div = $('<div id="templateID"></div>').css({

            "height": height,
            "width": width,
            "border": border

        });


        divLogicFactory.arraysOfDives.push($div);
    }
    return divLogicFactory;
});


var controllers = angular.module('controllers', ['jsonFactory','contentItemDirective','divLogic']);

controllers.controller("HomeController", function ($http,$scope, containerData,divLogicFactory) {

    console.log(divLogicFactory);


})]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Quick answer**

You should return custom promise `object` from outside `.then` function of `data.getDivData` rather than returning `$http` function(but creating overhead promise while dealing with `$http` calls is considered as anti-pattern). Don't go for this `Quick answer` part.

**Code**

```
data.getDivData = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer(), data = {};
    $http({
        method:"get",
        url:"App/metaData/divData.json"
    }).
        then(function(response){
        defer.resolve(response.data);
    },function(error){
        defer.reject(error);
        //return defer.promise; //removed from here
    })
    return defer.promise;
}
```

**Detailed**

You were not returned promise from correct part of your code.

Other than that you have created overhead promise which isn't needed in that place. As `$http` methods does return a promise object when do ajax call. You could utilize that way.

```
data.getDivData = function(){
    return $http.get('App/metaData/divData.json').then(function(response){
        //used .then here because you could have control over a data here
        //you validate some prevalidation stuff in data, which should be there
        //before returning data. otherwise you could just return.
        //exposing only part `response.data` to consumer, other part is abstracted.
        return response.data;
    },function(error){
        return error;
    });
    //OR you could just do below as @EProgrammerNotFound suggested.
    //return $http.get('App/metaData/divData.json')
};
```

Also you have DOM manipulation code there in place in `setDivsData` method which shouldn't be there. It would be better if you move that code inside a directive.

---

For getting `arraysOfDives` rendered using `setDivsData` you use promise chain so that the after creating of div gets completed you will return that arrayOfDives object.

**Factory**

```
 divLogicFactory.setDivsData = function () {
    return containerData.getDivData().then(function (data) {
        //extract divData from call back
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var
                height = data[i].height,
                width = data[i].width,
                border = data[i].border,
                positionY = data[i].positionTopY,
                positionX = data[i].positionLeftX,
                templateID = data[i].templateID;
            init(height, width, border, positionY, positionX, templateID);
        }
        return divLogicFactory.arraysOfDives; //return arraysOfDives
 });
```

**Controller**

```
controllers.controller("HomeController", function ($http, $scope, containerData, divLogicFactory) {

    divLogicFactory.setDivsData(data).then(function(){
        console.log(data); //
    });

})]
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, working well thank you again

Comment: i new in stackoverflow were do i accept answer? after pressing the up button over the "1" its tell me taht after 15 post i can do this

Comment: @wrcron1 do look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @wrcron1 Thanks :) the user who had downvoted should remove it I think :(